# Как реализовать функцию «Delay» (задержки) в love2d (lua)?

Tags: lua

Пожалуйста помогите с функцией "Delay" на языке lua с надстройкой love2d. Поискав в "Гугле" я нашел функции которые ОЧЕНЬ тормозят игру.
Для примера напишу отрывок из своего кода.

```
subspeed = 5 -- вычитание голода за одну минуту --

function hungersubstract(subspeed)
playerhunger = playerhunger - subspeed
-- Тут нужна задержка на одну минуту--
end
```

Comment: Извинения за траслит приравниваются к согласию на правку комментария ;) Одобрил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тормозят игру не найденные вами функции - а сам факт задержки. Когда вы ставите задержку - вы останавливаете всю программу целиком.

Вам надо обрабатывать событие [love.update](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.update), и там внутри производить обновления всех подобных значений. Не забудьте обязательно учитывать сколько времени прошло - иначе сложность вашей игры будет зависеть от характеристик компьютера пользователя.

```
function love.update(dt)
  -- ...
  playerhunger = playerhunger - subspeed * dt
  -- ...
end
```